# fixing android adb tab completion when running from windows 7

Tags: android, adb

anyone knows how to fix tab completion in adb on a windows machine ?
It seems to be doing the completion but not showing it on screen.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to do in command line. You can do it by cygwin.